# In TypeDoc, can I create a doc comment for a method a child class inherits from its parent without having to override that method in the child class?

Tags: typescript, typedoc

In TypeDoc, can I create a doc comment for a function a child class inherits from its parent without having to override that function in the child class and adding a doc comment to that override implementation?

I want to "override" the inherited doc comment for the child's function without having to implement that function as an override in the child class if possible.

```js
class Parent<T>
{
    readonly #tProp: T;

    public constructor(tArg: T)
    {
        this.#tProp = tArg;
    }

    /** Getter for the tProp */
    public tProp(): T { return this.#tProp; }
}

/*
 * Is it possible to add doc comment to replace doc comment
 * for tProp getter inherited from Parent class without having
 * to add override implementation for tProp getter?
 */
class Child extends Parent<string>
{
    public constructor(stringProp: string)
    {
        super(stringProp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to be possible with [`@property`](https://typedoc.org/tags/property/)

```
/**
 * @property tProp overriden description
 */
class Child extends Parent<string>
{
    public constructor(stringProp: string)
    {
        super(stringProp);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work in 0.25.0 due to [a bug](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/commit/6f3fb5744f61344cfa622ac1c97a8fcf20b3fa74) I just fixed, it will work in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the response and looking forward to the fix, I'll be sure to keep my eye out for it :D By any chance, will generic's types that can be inferred be shown in the generated documentation instead of the type parameter name?

The return type for the `Child.tProp()` method will show a return type of `T` when it could infer the return type as a `string`.

Comment: @Snap that's how it works today? I just copied your example locally and ran on it, it's displayed as `tProp(): string` as expected

Comment: Hmmm? That's odd, I have a project where explicitly having an override for the parent getter method is the only way to have the inferred return types shown. Except in the project, tProp is a **getter**: `public get tProp(): T {  return this.#tProp; }`, maybe that's why?